# Mistake in solving this simple inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose have the the inequality, where $x,y$ are variables,

$$
\frac{x+y}{2}\leq \frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}(x+y)
$$
Clearly, this is true if $\frac12 <\frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}$, but if I try to solve it by adding/subtracting I get 
$$
x(1-\frac{2\alpha}{\beta+\gamma})\leq y(\frac{2\alpha}{\beta+\gamma} -1) = -y(1-\frac{2\alpha}{\beta+\gamma})
$$
which gives, (assuming I am not dividing by a negative number, if are then flip the inequality sign )
$$
x\leq -y
$$
which is very different from $\frac12 <\frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}$?

Why do these two methods give very different results (or are they same and I am overlooking something?)

Comment: "Clearly, this is true if 12<αβ+γ"  .... Not if $x + y < 0$. If $x + y < 0$ then the exact opposite it true.

Comment: "(assuming I am not dividing by a negative number"  which is an assumption you may not make.

Comment: @fleablood Rigorously, yes, but what if we are dividing by a negative number just change the inequality sign around. What I am wondering is why whether I divide vs add/subtract I get different(-looking) inequalities, and how to interpret/deal with this.

Comment: But you don't have the flipped inequallity in your result.  Your result is the trivial $x \le -y$ or $x \ge -y$ which means... nothing.

Comment: @fleablood yes, but why does on method give me a trivial result on the other doesn't? I'm guessing it is because in one case I am solving for the $\frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}$ whereas in the other I am solving for $x$?

Comment: So you seem to get that if there are negatives you need to flip.  But you *don't* seem to get that actually *matters* and you actually have to *do* it in your answers.

Comment: "but why does on method give me a trivial result on the other doesn't"  Because you are not actually following through and doing every thing thoroughly.  You are acknowledging you need to flip and then *not doing it*.

Comment: @I see... if I do it by cases $x+y>0$ etc, then whether $1-2 \frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma} $ is $>$ or $(<)$ 0 give results that are not consistent with $x+y>0$, which lets me determine whether $1-2 \frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma} $ is greater or less than 0 (i.e. $\frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma} $ is greater or less than half). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 2:

$x(1-\frac{2\alpha}{\beta+\gamma})\leq y(\frac{2\alpha}{\beta+\gamma} -1) = -y(1-\frac{2\alpha}{\beta+\gamma})$

Case 1:  $1 = \frac {2\alpha}{\beta + \gamma}$

Then $0 = 0$ and nothing can be determined.

Case 2: $1 > \frac {2\alpha}{\beta + \gamma}$

Then $x\le -y$

Case 3: $1 < \frac {2\alpha}{\beta + \gamma}$

Then $x \ge -y$.

Method 1:

$\frac{x+y}{2}\leq \frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}(x+y)$

$(x+y) = \leq \frac{2\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}(x+y)$

Case 1:  $1 = \frac {2\alpha}{\beta + \gamma}$

The $x + y = x+y$ and nothing can be determined.

Case 2: $1 > \frac {2\alpha}{\beta + \gamma}$

The if $x+y > 0$ we would have $x+1 >  \frac {2\alpha}{\beta + \gamma}(x+y)$ but that is a contradiction.

So $x + y \le 0$ and $x \le -y$.

Case 3: $1 < \frac {2\alpha}{\beta + \gamma}$

If $x + y < 0$ we would have $x+1 >  \frac {2\alpha}{\beta + \gamma}(x+y)$ but that is a contradiction.

So we have $x + y \ge 0$ and $x \ge -y$.

...

so both methods come to same conclusion.

Comment: Side question: If we have more complicated inequalities, or more inequalities, these approach seem like they could result in a large amount of cases? (perhaps more than are manageable by hand?)

Answer (score 1):

We have three cases for $\beta+\gamma\neq 0$

- $x+y> 0 $

$$\frac{x+y}{2}\leq \frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}(x+y)\iff \frac{1}{2}\leq \frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}$$

- $x+y< 0 $

$$\frac{x+y}{2}\leq \frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}(x+y)\iff \frac{1}{2}\geq \frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}$$

- $x+y= 0$ it is always true that

$$\frac{x+y}{2}\leq \frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}(x+y)$$

Comment: But how come the resulting inequality looks different if I rearrange to get $x$ and $y$ on different sides versus if i divide out $(x+y)$?

Comment: @user106860 Recall that when we divide an inequality by a quantity we need to reverse the sign if the quantity is negative.

Comment: That's just solving for different variables.  If $\frac 12 \le \frac \alpha{\beta + \gamma}$ then $x + y \ge 0$ and $x \ge -y$.  If $\frac 12 \ge $ then $x + y \le 0$ and $x \le -y$.